# Meteor upload clearing/resetting form data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**Problem:** form data in meteor is set using a link click, but does not reset/update when a new link is clicked. This causes all following link clicks to point to the initial clicked document (instead of the newly clicked one) because formData does not update/reset after each click

I have a test webapp (http://meteorpad.com/pad/ckgN6GL4msQn4Ms5h/Jobs) where links in the nav menu call up different documents from a collection and display the data

Part of the data display is an upload section. When a link is clicked, the id of that document is stored in a session variable. This then gets passed as id in formData, so that the uploader can create a directory with the same name as the document id. Files uploaded for that document then get stored in that specific folder

This works for the first link that I click. Files get uploaded to the subdirectory bearing its name. However, when I click a new link, any files I upload get uploaded to the first documents directory

I believe this is because the form does not get reloaded, therefore formData still has the id of the first clicked document link.

With this sort of setup, how do I reset the form data whenever a link is clicked, so that it is always passing the latest id, and not the first one?

In this code, when a link is clicked, its ID is stored in a session variable:

```
Template.job.events({
        "click #jobItem": function(event){
            Session.set("selectedJob", this._id);
        }
    });
```

The document info is displayed with a template like this:

```
<template name="summary">
  {{#with summary}}
  <div id="summaryContainer">
    <p>Name: {{name}}</p>
    <p>Created at: {{createdAt}}</p>
    <p>Username: {{username}}</p>
    <p>Script location:</p>
    {{> upload_bootstrap multiple=false formData=specificFormData}}
    <p>Upload file location:</p>

    <button class="deleteJob">Delete Job</button>
    <button class="saveJob">Save</button>
    <button class="startJob">Start</button>
  </div>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

So the upload form called `specificFormData` which is a summary template helper function:

```
Template.summary.helpers({
        summary: function(){
            var curJob = Session.get("selectedJob");
            return Jobs.findOne( { _id:curJob } );
        },

        specificFormData: function(){
            return({
                id: Session.get("selectedJob")
            })
        }
    });
```

The uploader definition creates a subdirectory using the formData ID that was pulled from the session variable:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    var dir = '/job/';

    UploadServer.init({
        uploadDir: process.env.PWD + dir,
        tmpDir: process.env.PWD + dir + 'tmp/',
        checkCreateDirectories: true,
        getDirectory: function(fileInfo, formData){
            return formData.id;
        }
    });
});
```

So when a job is first clicked, a session variable is stored. The display page then pulls just that documents info from the collection. Form data stores the ID and creates the subdirectory using the job ID. When a link is clicked again, the form data ID does not get reset, and tries to upload to the same previous directory and not the newly clicked document directory. **It should upload to a different subdirectory depending on which job was clicked**

Comment: I have tried just about everything that I could think of with no luck. I did find out that before anything is selected for upload you could switch between jobs and the "data-form-data" attribute in the upload form (inspect the browse button) would change. After you have selected a file for upload, this value is unchangeable until you reload the page. I'm pretty sure that if you were to use a router you could get around this problem ([flow router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) or [iron router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug and according to [this issue](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads/issues/148) it should have been fixed in `tomi:upload-jquery v2.2.0` but it seems to be still occurring as seen in your example.

Here's an alternative solution. Use `callbacks` instead of `formData` and add a callback function with the form data as a template helper.

main.html

```
<template name="summary">
    {{> upload_bootstrap multiple=false callbacks=myCallbacks}}
</template>
```

common.js

```
Template.summary.helpers({
    myCallbacks: function() {
        return {
            formData: function() { return({id: Session.get("selectedJob")}) }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice find on the bug. I tried the callback solution and couldn't get it to work. Were you able to get working?

Comment: Yes, callback works fine. Here's a fixed version of @Simon's repo: http://meteorpad.com/pad/j7XDhrDdWJeTRsH5c/Jobs-Fix. You'll have to download it to test it yourself because Simon didn't include any tests.

Comment: I am having issues with the exact same thing. I set two different Session variables from an input and select box. I listen on change events and set the variables accordingly but the Uploader doesn't actually send the data. Whatever value was set in the session variable when I click the "Browse ..." button, is being sent to the server. Any clues?

Comment: @vinzenzweber last time I checked, the method only allowed you to attach a file once and you were not able to overwrite it. You are able to overwrite it using a callback as I mentioned in the post however.

Comment: I created a pull request to fix this issue: https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-tomi-upload-jquery/pull/9